# HTML Elements cut off?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm working with twitter bootstrap and I'm using their popover to show some info about a movie.

But it gets just cut off! Like the image below.

This JSFidde: http://jsfiddle.net/uGKAz/ shows the problem
But in this JSFidde the problem isnt there..
http://jsfiddle.net/uGKAz/1/
So it seems as the surrounding elements is causing it..

**Also, if I had the popover positioned to 'right' instead of 'left' I would get the same cut-off line, but the right of the popover instead.**

I've added a style to the

element in boostrap.js:

```
, template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p style="display:inline-block;"></p></div></div></div>'
```

Here's how the error looks:
[image]

Adding image showing the full element selected in Chrome:
[image]

Comment: The image in your post doesn't load.

Comment: Try adding 'float: left' your inner container CSS rule.

Comment: Really? I can see it + I can see it on my cell.

Comment: There is probably an overflow hidden in the css?

Comment: The image works for me. However, could you add more of the relevant code or a JSFiddle or something?

Comment: Ill try fix up a jsfiddle

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uGKAz/

Comment: maybe there is a z-index problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TADA, the overflow hidden:**

inspect the following div

```
<div id="second_row" style="">
```